# I want a peer review, but the code cannot be copy-pasted on a question

Tags: discussion

I've created an opensource library wrapping some JDBC functions. I'm not satisfied with JUnit tests, and I would like it to be peer reviewed. The code is not so much and it shouldn't be reviewed line by line, just a general look by someone else would be really helpful to me. But it is too much to be copy-pasted on a question.
There are no specific portions of code to be reviewed, I'm looking for a general opinion, also to verify the fitness for use and identify gaps. I'm looking for constructive criticisms.

Is this the correct site or this is just for posting large portions of code you want others to inspect for errors?

Comment: This question+answer is a gem!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> There are no specific portions of code to be reviewed, I'm looking for a general opinion, also to verify the fitness for use and identify gaps.

If that's the case, I don't think you're going to have much luck. What we do on this site is review specific pieces of code (preferably fairly small pieces). Tom Gilb and Dorothy Graham, in their book *Software Inspection*, recommend reviewing at most a few hundred lines at a time: more than that and inspection becomes onerous and defects are missed.

You could try posting a representative subset of your code: a function or a class, perhaps. It's possible that you'll get useful comments that you can then apply to the whole program.

Comment: I see... thank you!